# Consulta muestra registros en diferentes tablas

Tags: php, pdo

El problema es que tengo dos registros en la tabla formacion, lo que quiero es que muestre en la misma tabla ambos registros ya que se deberia ver como un Curriculum para luego imprimir. Lo que pasa es que se crean dos tablas y en cada una muestra un registro. Este es mi codigo, no realizo la consulta despues del "thead" porque debajo tengo mas tablas y registros que mostrar:

```
<?php 

  $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=proyecto1","root",""); 
  $sql=$pdo->prepare("SELECT u.*, dp.*, f.* FROM usuarios u
  INNER JOIN datospersonales dp ON u.documento = dp.documento
  INNER JOIN formacion f ON u.documento = f.documento
  WHERE u.documento = '".$_SESSION['usuario']['documento']."' ");
  $sql->execute();
  $registros=$sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
  if($sql -> rowCount() > 0)   { 
    foreach($registros as $registro) {
?>
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <section class="content">
      <div class= "row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="box box-info">
            <div class="box-body box-profile">
              <img class="profile-user-img img-responsive img-circle" src="dist/img/avatar3.png" alt="User profile picture"><br>
              <h3 class="profile-username text-center"> <?php   echo $_SESSION['usuario']['nombres']; echo "  "; echo $_SESSION['usuario']['apellidos']; ?></h3>
            </div> 
    <!--tabla-->
    <section id="formacion">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 ">
          <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header"><h3 class="box-title">Formación y Capacitacion</h3></div>
            <div class="box-body table-responsive">
              <table class="table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Titulo</th>
                    <th>Nivel de Estudio</th>
                    <th>Institución</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $registro->titulo_carrera?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $registro->nivel_estudio?></td>                      
                    <td><?php echo $registro->universidad?></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>                            
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
     <?php }} ?>  
          </div> 
        </div>
      </div>
      <center><button type="button"  class="btn btn-success" onclick="window.print()">Imprimir</button></center>
    </section>
  </div>
?>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes colocar un `var_dump($registros)` despues del `if` para ver como trae la consulta?

Answer (score 0):

Debes recorrer los valores en la parte que lo quieres mostrar, es decir en la tabla, aparte de eso también me he permitido indentar el código y algunas correcciones menores.

Tu código podría quedar algo así:

```
<?php

    $Connection = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=proyecto1","root","");

    // acomodamos la consulta y definimos el parámetro que le vamos a pasar
    $statement = $Connection->prepare("SELECT
            usuarios.*,
            datospersonales.*,
            formacion.*
        FROM usuarios
        INNER JOIN datospersonales ON usuarios.documento = datospersonales.documento
        INNER JOIN formacion ON u.documento = formacion.documento
        WHERE
            u.documento = :mi_parametro"
    );

    // ejecutamos la consula y le pasamos el parametro que necesita
    $statement->execute([
        'mi_parametro' => $_SESSION['usuario']['documento']
    ]);

    // Obtenemos los datos como un objeto
    $fomaciones = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    // comprobamos si hay datos
    if ($statement->rowCount() > 0) {
        ?>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <section class="content">
                <div class= "row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="box box-info">
                            <div class="box-body box-profile">
                                <img class="profile-user-img img-responsive img-circle" src="dist/img/avatar3.png" alt="User profile picture">
                                <br>
                                <h3 class="profile-username text-center">
                                    <?php echo $_SESSION['usuario']['nombres']; echo "  "; echo $_SESSION['usuario']['apellidos']; ?>
                                </h3>
                            </div>
                            <!--tabla-->
                            <section id="formacion">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 ">
                                        <div class="box">
                                            <div class="box-header">
                                                <h3 class="box-title">Formación y Capacitacion</h3>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="box-body table-responsive">
                                                <table class="table">
                                                    <thead>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th>Título</th>
                                                            <th>Nivel de Estudio</th>
                                                            <th>Institución</th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <?php
                                                            // aquí recorremos los resultados
                                                            foreach ($formaciones as $formacion) {
                                                                ?>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td><?= $formacion->titulo_carrera ?></td>
                                                                        <td><?= $formacion->nivel_estudio ?></td>
                                                                        <td><?= $formacion->universidad ?></td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                <?php
                                                            }
                                                        ?>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </section>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <center><button type="button"  class="btn btn-success" onclick="window.print()">Imprimir</button></center>
            </section>
        </div>
        <?php
    } // Cerramos el if
?>
```

Fijate en la parte del `<tbody>` de la tabla es donde recorremos los resultados:

```
<table class="table">
    <!-- Cabecera de la tabla omitida para mejor presentación-->
    <tbody>
        <?php
            // aquí recorremos los resultados
            foreach ($formaciones as $formacion) {
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?= $formacion->titulo_carrera ?></td>
                        <td><?= $formacion->nivel_estudio ?></td>
                        <td><?= $formacion->universidad ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: El problema es que tengo más tablas abajo, en ese caso debo realizar la consulta completa para cada tabla? he probado colocando el   foreach ($formaciones as $formacion) en cada una pero se duplican los registros @Xerif